# Floated parent only extended by content floated divs

Tags: html, css, css-float, parent-child, center

I have some divs holidng images I want to display. 
They are within a centered container. 
This container has a variable width so depending on your browser size you have either 3 or 4 images in a row before they go flow into the next row. I want to have thoses images centered in the container elment. My problem now is, that this container element is always 100% so but the inside image divs do not fill it. I need the inner divs to expand the out div, so it is only as wide as all the 3 or 4 images and their margin.

My html is:

```
<div id='team'>
  <div class='item-container'>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='small.jpg' alt='' />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='item-container'>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='small.jpg' alt='' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css is:

```
#team{
  margin: 20px 0px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#team .item-container{
  position: relative;   
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  height: 180px;    
  margin: 2%;
}
```

Anyone any ideas? If you do not get what I mean, please ask so I can describe it in more detail. Thanks in advance.

[image: wireframe]

Comment: It's not obvious to me - http://jsfiddle.net/gGc76/. Can you try to refine the problem?

Comment: Sure, it is like this.   
http://jsfiddle.net/gGc76/1/

Comment: Is the main container div#team with a padding: 0 auto instead of a margin: o auto to center it?

Comment: Sorry, corrected it. "padding: 20px 0;" Makes no difference though. It is centered by beein inside a centered element. I can not center it in there because it always has a width of 100%. The centering of this "wrapper" (#team) is not included in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to using `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` on the `.item`s, and then `text-align: center` on `#team` to center:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/gGc76/8/ - *(be sure to try resizing the window)*

You possibly don't want `float: left` on `#team`, but I'm not sure what you're doing.

```
#team {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 20px 0;

    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;

    text-align: center
}
#team .item-container {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    /* if you need ie7 support */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;

    position: relative;   
    width: 230px;
    height: 180px;    
    margin: 2%;
    background: #eee
}
```

Comment: Dude, you definitly kicked the shit out of this code and it is pretty awesome. Sadly it is not 100% what I want.  
I would rather have it so that the item-container divs beeing for e.g. 250px at the moment and 3 in a row make it so that #team is 750px wide. This way I can center it. The problem now is, that the last two elements for e.g. are supposed to be to the left and not in the middle. I might have not made that clear, sorry. Do you also have any idea how I get this behavior? I would be delighted. :) Thanks so far.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you're after here. You want a horizontally centered container, with a maximum width of ~1000px (to fit 4 images), and a minimum width of 250px (to fit one image). The items inside should be left aligned. Is that right?

Comment: Okay, I added an image of what I want. I hope this makes it more understandable than my explanation. Thanks

Comment: Well, since nobody seems to have another solution, I just agree to yours, it is a pretty good one and very efficient for most cases. I now decided on using a little javascript to fix it. Thanks again.